# joomla section error

Tags: joomla

I have a site http://alternex.onlineja.com 
I am using gavick pro modules (www.gavickpro.com)

The products menu is linked to a section/blog layout, I have two modules on it,

whenever I click an article from any of the modules, it doesnt show the article,
it shows the section, i.e. it doesnt go anywhere.

If I create a new menu and modules and link them together, 
the articles go back to the products page listing.

I am not sure how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The URLs are different. The "bad" page linked from the products page has `&Itemid=79` on the end, so see if you can get rid of that somehow.

But since it's a third-party module, you might be better asking on their forum if they have one, or support channel.